# Data found after session invalidate

Tags: java, tomcat, httpsession, ofbiz

I'm working with a framework and getting an issue which i can't get to the end of.

We have the following code:

```
    String returnValue = LoginWorker.logout(request, response);

    ShoppingCart newShoppingCart = ShoppingCartEvents.getCartObject(request);
```

Which, in short details, does the following:
logs out the user (framework code!), and creates a new shopping cart.

This code is from the logout:

```
  // now empty out the session
    session.invalidate();
    session = request.getSession(true);
```

So we definitely have a new session. Now, in the shopping cart constructor, this is the code used to set up a field (which is causing my problem):

```
       this.orderPartyId = (String) session.getAttribute("orderPartyId");
```

This data shouldn't be anything but NULL, because this value in the session is not set anywere after logout.
This, neither on my local env, neither on the staging (UAT) system, doesn't happen. Only on live, which i cannot really explain.

The framework is Apache Ofbiz, but i'm pretty sure this is not specific.

Did anyone, ever, experience something like this.

Comment: In local, your attribute is not `null`, but in production, it is `null`?

Comment: In the other way around. And it causes an issue on production.

Comment: That's weird. Are there any major difference between your dev and production environments?

Comment: There is a loadbalancer on live.

Comment: Maybe session replication is messing with everything.